# How to find and get rid of consecutive repeated punctuation signs without using regular expressions in python?

Tags: python, punctuation

I want to get rid of repeated consecutive punctuation signs and only leave one of them.

If I have 
`string = 'Is it raining????'`,
I want to get
`string = 'Is it raining?'`
But I don't want to get rid of `'...'`

I also need to do this without using regular expressions. I am a beginner in python and would appreciate any advice or hint. Thanks :)

Comment: do you want to do that exclusively on question marks?

Comment: What have you tried, and what precisely is the problem with it? Why can't you use regex?

Comment: @taesu No, any punctuation sign

Comment: anything except periods?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am in a project and the person I am working for doesn't want me to use regular expressions. To be honest I am not sure where to start from since my knowledge of python is very elementary

Comment: Why do you need to do this without using Regular Expressions? I'm a big fan of using Python's `str` methods when practical, but this sort of task is _definitely_ suited to using Regular Expressions. OTOH, you could use `itertools.groupby()`.

Comment: *"I am not sure where to start from since my knowledge of python is very elementary"* - then you are not yet ready to ask a question here. Consider following a basic tutorial to get to grips with the language.

Answer (score 5):

Yet another `groupby` approach:

```
from itertools import groupby 
from string import punctuation

punc = set(punctuation) - set('.')

s = 'Thisss is ... a test!!! string,,,,, with 1234445556667 rrrrepeats????'
print(s)

newtext = []
for k, g in groupby(s):
    if k in punc:
        newtext.append(k)
    else:
        newtext.extend(g)

print(''.join(newtext))
```

**output**

```
Thisss is ... a test!!! string,,,,, with 1234445556667 rrrrepeats????
Thisss is ... a test! string, with 1234445556667 rrrrepeats?
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the following kind of approach:

```
import string

text = 'Is it raining???? No,,,, but...,,,, it is snoooowing!!!!!!!'

for punctuation in string.punctuation:
    if punctuation != '.':
        while True:
            replaced =  text.replace(punctuation * 2, punctuation)
            if replaced == text:
                break
            text = replaced

print(text)
```

This would give the following output:

```
Is it raining? No, but..., it is snoooowing!
```

Or for a more efficient version giving the same results:

```
import string

text = 'Is it raining???? No,,,, but...,,,, it is snoooowing!!!!!!!'
last = None
output = []

for c in text:
    if c == '.':
        output.append(c)
    elif c != last:
        if c in string.punctuation:
            last = c
        else:
            last = None
        output.append(c)

print(''.join(output))
```

Comment: use of `string.punctuation` would be nice

Comment: This, unfortunately, will only work if the repeated pattern occurs once. If in the string there is an additional position where there is repetition, the code will remove all occurrences of the punctuation.

Comment: Can you provide an example that does not work? The first example uses `while True` to ensure all patterns are replaced. The example shows two groups of `,,,,` being replaced.

Answer (score 0):

```
import string
from itertools import groupby

# get all punctuation minus period.
puncs = set(string.punctuation)-set('.')
s = 'Is it raining???? No but...,,,, it is snowing!!!!!!!###!@#@@@@'

# get count of consecutive characters
t = [[k,len(list(g))] for k, g in groupby(s)]

s = ''
for ele in t:
    char = ele[0]
    count = ele[1]
    if char in puncs and count > 1:
        count = 1
    s+=char*count

print s
#Is it raining? No but..., it is snowing!#!@#@
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from itertools import groupby

s = 'Is it raining???? okkkk!!! ll... yeh""" ok?'
replaceables = [ch for i, ch in enumerate(s) if i > 0 and s[i - 1] == ch and (not ch.isalpha() and ch != '.')]
replaceables = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(replaceables)]

start = 0
for replaceable in replaceables:
    replaceable = ''.join(replaceable)
    start = s.find(replaceable, start)
    r = s[start:].replace(replaceable, '', 1)
    s = s.replace(s[start:], r)
print s
```

Comment: what if `s = 'assassin`'?

Comment: Another test case this fails on: `'a!!b!'`